# Why are my Rails sessions and cookies not persisting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cookiestore

I have a Rails 4.0/Ruby 2.0 app with bare bones devise, and I added a feature to retain the main index page filter settings by way of an ajax call to the relevant controller, which stores them in session[:filter]. The session data (by way of CookieStore) is not persisting across requests as it ordinarily would. I've also tried using the cookies object and devise's user_session as well with the same result.

The devise session data works fine for authentication. I am making no other session assignments besides this. Is there something I should look for in <%= debug session %>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would verify if the ajax call is passing the authenticity token as a param. Rails clears the session if the authenticity token is not present in the ajax call, that comes from this line of code in the application_controller.rb:

```
protect_from_forgery
```

Comment: Thanks. Although my solution was to use activerecord::store instead (instant gratification), I'm accepting this answer because it almost certainly points in the right direction... Ajax and session security are given short shrift in most Rails primers.

Comment: I'm having this issue today. I set a cookie or session variable in one action, and in another action, the value is nil. No ajax is even involved. Just literally setting a cookie/session variable in the show action, and getting a nil value in the new action. @DanHoyt